# clear value in keychain when user logout

Tags: ios, swift, keychain

I want to remove keychain value form my service, when user has logout. However, I feel confused about the best practice way to do that.

Here is my service

```
let userAccount = "AuthenticatedUser"
let accessGroup = "SecuritySerivice"

let passwordKey = "KeyForPassword"

let kSecClassValue = NSString(format: kSecClass)
let kSecAttrAccountValue = NSString(format: kSecAttrAccount)
let kSecValueDataValue = NSString(format: kSecValueData)
let kSecClassGenericPasswordValue = NSString(format: kSecClassGenericPassword)
let kSecAttrServiceValue = NSString(format: kSecAttrService)
let kSecMatchLimitValue = NSString(format: kSecMatchLimit)
let kSecReturnDataValue = NSString(format: kSecReturnData)
let kSecMatchLimitOneValue = NSString(format: kSecMatchLimitOne)

public class KeychainService: NSObject {

    public class func savePassword(token: String) {
        self.save(service: passwordKey, data: token)
    }

    public class func loadPassword() -> String? {
        return self.load(service: passwordKey)
    }

    public class func removePassword() {

    }

    private class func save(service: String, data: String) {
        let dataFromString: Data = data.data(using: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue), allowLossyConversion: false)!

        let keychainQuery: NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(objects: [kSecClassGenericPasswordValue, service, userAccount, dataFromString], forKeys: [kSecClassValue, kSecAttrServiceValue, kSecAttrAccountValue, kSecValueDataValue])

        SecItemDelete(keychainQuery as CFDictionary)

        SecItemAdd(keychainQuery as CFDictionary, nil)
    }

    private class func load(service: String) -> String? {

        let keychainQuery: NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(objects: [kSecClassGenericPasswordValue, service, userAccount, kCFBooleanTrue, kSecMatchLimitOneValue], forKeys: [kSecClassValue, kSecAttrServiceValue, kSecAttrAccountValue, kSecReturnDataValue, kSecMatchLimitValue])

        var dataTypeRef :AnyObject?

        // Search for the keychain items
        let status: OSStatus = SecItemCopyMatching(keychainQuery, &dataTypeRef)
        var contentsOfKeychain: String? = nil

        if status == errSecSuccess {
            if let retrievedData = dataTypeRef as? Data {
                contentsOfKeychain = String(data: retrievedData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
            }
        } else {
            print("KEY: Nothing was retrieved from the keychain. Status code \(status)")
        }

        return contentsOfKeychain
    }

    private class func remove(service: String) {

    }

}
```

Obviously, I'm not shure whether I should remove anything form keychain actually

Answer (score 2):

To remove username password in Keychain use

```
   func removeUserFromKeychain() {
        let spec: NSDictionary = [kSecClass: kSecClassGenericPassword]
        SecItemDelete(spec)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete the item using KeychainItemWrapper, use -resetKeychainItem. This calls SecItemDelete() with the correct value.

Answer (score -1):

You can clear your data. Please try below lines

```
keychain["yourKey"] = nil
```

or

```
do {
try keychain.remove("yourKey")
} catch let error {
print("error: \(error)")
}
```

Thanks